# Node child process, not getting the output from CLI

Tags: node.js, heroku-cli

I am trying to run a basic cmd command with a child process, i am testing some cli's with nodejs and can't understand why i am not getting any output, here is a simple example:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
let child = spawn('cmd.exe',['/K'])
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
});

child.stdin.write('heroku login\n');
```

The output should be :

```
heroku: 

Enter your login credentials

Email :
```

what am i missing? Thx

**Update:**

I have been playing with the code and could get what i want:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
let child = spawn('heroku',['login' ,'-i']);

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {        
    child.stdin.write('email@hotmail.com');
});
```

Once the stderr.on fired i have to enter the email address
but after i call `child.stdin.write('email@hotmail.com');` i am getting an error:

```
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone let me know what might be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything to solve it but by researching online i found node-pty (https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty) that do the job, for windows, you have to install some extra applications but works with most CLI's that i tested, here is a simple example:

```
var os = require('os');
var pty = require('node-pty');

var shell = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';
var ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, ['heroku login -i'], {
    name: 'heroku',
    cwd: process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env
});
ptyProcess.write('my@email.com\r');
ptyProcess.write('password\r');
ptyProcess.on('data', function(data) {
    ptyProcess.write('\n');
    process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

and here is another one:

```
var os = require('os');
var pty = require('node-pty');

var shell = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';
var ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, ['vue create app'], {
    name: 'vue',
    cwd: process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env
});
ptyProcess.write('keydown');
ptyProcess.on('data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data.toString().trim());
});
```

Comment: How could you change the shell dynamically after running pty.spawn?